# Create OU´s and Active Directory users in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I tried to do an script in PowerShell to manage Organizative Units, users group and users but it doesn't work. My domain is ras2017.org. I am the domain Administrator, and I works with only 1 server machine.

```
#Creating the UO

New-ADOrganizationalUnit Profesorado
New-ADOrganizationalUnit Alumnado 
#Creamos los grupos de usuarios

New-ADGroup -Name "Profesorado" -SamAccountName Profesorado -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName "Profesorado" -Path " OU=Profesorado,DC=ras2017,DC=org " -Description "Grupo del profesorado"
New-ADGroup -Name "Alumnado" -SamAccountName Alumnado -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -DisplayName "Alumnado" -Path " OU=Alumnado,DC=ras2017,DC=org " -Description "Alumnado"

#Creating users

New-ADUser -Name Rafa -GivenName Rafa -Surname Aybar -Path "OU=Alumnado,DC=ras2017,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
New-ADUser -Name Al1 -GivenName Al1 -Surname 2 -Path "OU=Alumnado,DC=ras2017,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
New-ADUser -Name Al2-GivenName Al2 -Surname 2 -Path "OU=Alumnado,DC=ras2017,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
New-ADUser -Name Prof1 -GivenName 1 -Surname 1 -Path "OU=Profesorado,DC=ras2017,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
New-ADUser -Name Prof2 -GivenName 2 -Surname 2 -Path "OU=Profesorado,DC=ras2017,DC=org" -accountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Rafa-1994" -Force)
#adding users to groups

Add-ADGroupMember "Alumnado" Rafa,Al1,Al2
Add-ADGroupMember "Profesorado" Prof1,Prof2
```

It gives me this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrador.WIN-481D680G638> New-ADOrganizationalUnit "Profesorado"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit : No se pudo encontrar ningún servidor predeterminado
que ejecutara Servicios web de Active Directory.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ New-ADOrganizationalUnit "Profesorado"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADServerDownException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1355,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnit
```

Comment: `CN=Alumnado,...` -> `OU=Alumnado,...`

Comment: I changed this but does not work

Comment: How *exactly* does it "not work"?

Comment: The cmdlet can't find a DC running [ADWS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908.aspx). Verify that the service is installed, running, and accessible from your local computer.

Comment: I have ADWS installed but stopped and I cant start this http://imgur.com/a/36FgM

Comment: Is the computer where you're running these commands a domain controller? Is your user a domain admin?

Comment: Yes, I am the domain Admin

Comment: Look, nobody except you is sitting in front of your computer, so if you want anybody to provide assistance anytime soon, you need to give us a far more complete picture of your environment, what exactly you're doing, and where exactly you're doing it. Please [edit] your question to do so. I'm not going to play Twenty Questions in the comments.

Comment: I have edited this

Answer (score 0):

"PS C:\Users\Administrador.WIN-481D680G638>"
The above is the start of the error message you posted. This indicates to me that you are logged in as Administrator on machine WIN-481D680G638. Is this a domain controller? Is this a Network account?

" + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADServerDownException"

The above indicates that the script is not able to reach a computer hosting AD so it cannot create the OU. Try running a simple AD command as this user from this machine and see if it works. "Get-ADUser JDoe". Also you could run:

New-ADOrganizationalUnit Profesorado -Whatif

This will probably generate the same error. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I run the machine where I have installed AD, and I am also the Administrator